# symfony2 ajax select without transformers and custom query builder

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I try to create ajax input based on symfony2 inputs.

Here is a concept ajax_input.

I create twig override code to implement ajax select2 - works well. I need to send only initial data from form or selected value. But have some problems with this. I use attr path with route name translated to select2 in twig.

In symfony I put

```
 ->add('contact', 'ajax_input',array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Contact',
                    'attr'=>array('path'=>'route_suggest'),
                )
            )
```

If I create ajax_input based on entity, I have ready to use input but...
If I have 1000 rows in this entity, I get it on input.

When I add own query builder

```
 'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        $builder = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
                        $builder->setMaxResults(10);
                        return $builder;
                    }
```

If this is new form it's ok, but if this is an edit form, I don't get my selected value because it's not in first 10 rows.

So I must add like here

'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($entity) {

```
                    $builder = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');

                    if($entity->getContact()){
                        $builder->where('u.id = :id')->setParameter('id',$entity->getContact()->getId());
                        $builder->setMaxResults(1);
                    }else{

                        $builder->setMaxResults(10);
                    }

                    return $builder;
                }
```

This doesn't look nice - I have many forms and looking for clean way. I want only put 2 necessary data - class name, suggest path for ajax.

Maybe I need to override `setDefaultOptions` in base class for entity input -`Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType` but don't know for now how to do it - this class only prepare `QueryBuilder` so how to decide get selected option or limit queries?

I also try to extends not entity input but choice input. show input is easy but is harder to save it - validator don't allow ajax data. Any examples what I found is putting many code to form - I don't want it. I need easy to use in many forms so it can by a new input but should work without many lines query builder or transformers for every entity.

I cannot find where symfony try to use transformer. Maybe it is easier to add 
`__toInteger()` function and if class have it don't request transformer?